# Getting many undefined calls when running , each function is saying that it is undefined

Tags: javascript

I am getting undefined values everywhere, its very annoying. I believe it might be a problem the way Im setting up the input with const

```
const prod = new Product();
prod
```

or is it something else ? I believe have try to fix some functions, like return this for buy product and fixing my toLowerCase with a null.

```
var products = [];
class Product {
   constructor(productName, amount, cost) {
       this.productName = productName,
        this.amount = amount,
        this.cost = cost
   }

   buyProduct(product){
       products.push(product);
       return this;

   }
   deleteProduct(str){
       var found = products.find(function(element){
       })
       if(found)
       {
           if(found.amount>1)

           }
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning `this` from all your methods, so you cannot chain all of them.

- `sumPrice()` only returns this if the item is found
- `deleteProduct()` does not return this
- `sumTotal()` neither

Also, your code was severely broken. Here is a list a fixes I made to make it work:

- Return this in all methods.
- use the same property name for `amount` and `quantity`
- use the same property name for `item` and `productName`
- use numbers instead of strings for `amount` and `cost`
- remove constructor, it was never called
- use `let/const` instead of `var`

I also changed the name of the `Product` class to `ProductsStore` since your class manages all your products and not only one, so I moved the `products[]` array inside the class and initialized it in the constructor.

```js
class ProductsStore {
  constructor() {
    this.products = [];
  }

  buyProduct(product) {
    this.products.push(product);
    return this;
  }
  
  deleteProduct(str) {
    const found = this.products.find(el =>
      el.productName.toLowerCase() == str.toLowerCase())
    if (found) {
      if (found.amount > 1) {
        const foundIndex = this.products.findIndex(x => x.productName.toLowerCase() === str.toLowerCase());
        this.products[foundIndex].amount = found.amount - 1;
      } else {
        this.products.splice(this.products.findIndex(
          item => item.productName.toLowerCase() === str.toLowerCase()), 1)
      }
    }
    return this;
  }
   
  sumPrice(str, num) {
    const foundIndex = this.products.findIndex(x => (x.productName || '').toLowerCase() === str.toLowerCase());
    if (foundIndex >= 0) {
      this.products[foundIndex].cost = this.products[foundIndex].cost + num;
    }
    return this;
  }

  sumTotal() {
    this.total = 0;
    for (let obj of this.products) {
      this.total += obj.amount * obj.cost;
    }
    return this;
  }
  
  write() {
    let total = 0;
    for (let obj of this.products) {
      console.log('Item: ' + obj.productName + ' | Quantity:' + obj.amount + ' | Price:' + obj.cost);
      total += obj.amount * obj.cost;
    }
    console.log('$' + total);
  }
}

new ProductsStore()
  .buyProduct({ productName: 'jameson', amount: 1, cost: 0 })
  .buyProduct({ productName: 'bud light', amount: 3, cost: 0 })
  .buyProduct({ productName: 'corona', amount: 4, cost: 0 })
  .buyProduct({ productName: 'beer', amount: 1, cost: 0 })
  .sumPrice('tequila', 5.99)
  .deleteProduct('corona')
  .sumPrice('beer', 5.04)
  .sumTotal()
  .write();
```

Comment: please delete this answer thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should return "this" from all of your methods.

Some methods aren't returning "this", like :

**sumPrice()**:

```
if(foundIndex>=0)
   {
       products[foundIndex].cost = products[foundIndex].cost + num;
   }
return this;// this should be returned here.
```

**deleteProduct()** :

should return "this" at the end of the function.

**sumTotal()**:

Instead of returning the total you should return this.

in the end, you should return a getter for the total.